# XSLT: How to discard unwanted HTML nodes from source?

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I am using `XSLT 1.0`, and using `xsltproc` on OS X Yosemite.
The source content is HTML; the target content is XML.

The issue is a fairly common one.  I want all "uninteresting"
nodes simply to be discarded from the output.  I've seen catch-all
directives like this:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|script"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This is close to what I need.  But unfortunately, it's too strong when I need to add another template that visits one of the text nodes caught by `node()`.  For example, suppose I added this template:

```
<xsl:template match="a/div[@class='location']/br">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

which simply replaces certain <br/> elements with spaces.
Well, `node()` precludes this latter template from taking effect,
because the relevant text node containing the line-break is discarded
already!

Well, to correct the issue, here's what I have done in lieu of the catch-all `node()`:

```
<xsl:template match="html/head|div[@id='banner_parent']|button|ul|div[@id='feed_title']|span|div[@class='submit_event']|script"/>
```

But this is precisely the problem:  I am now piecing together a template
whose matching criteria is likely to be error-prone when the source
content changes.

Is there a simpler directive that would accomplish the same thing?  I'm aiming for something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[not(locations)]|script"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question (a small example of the input and the expected output would be very helpful). It seems to me you want to learn about template priorities: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#conflict

Comment: Define 'uninteresting'. For that matter, define 'interesting'.

Comment: I need the template matching a/div[@class='location'/br to work; that is the interesting node.  But the catch-all template matching `node()` appears to work first -- i.e., after it takes effect, the a/div/br template has no nodes to work on.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your question to show a sample of your input HTML and the output you expect in this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you want only some nodes in the output and the rest you dont care abour, in this example I try to catch only li elements and throw the rest away.. not sure if this is what you want though http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiKk

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<!-- Lets pretend li is interesting for you -->
<xsl:template match="li">
<xsl:text>Interesting Node Only!
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```